How did Jost Bürgi's logarithms work?
According to what I have gathered from the internet Jost Bürgi came up with the idea of logarithms (as he called Progress Tabulen) after learning a correspondence between arithmetic and geometric sequences. We know this as the product rule for exponents: if $n \longleftrightarrow a^n$ and $m \longleftrightarrow a^m,$ then $$n+m \longleftrightarrow a^n\times a^m.$$
From what I understood, he first computed $r^n$ for $r=1.0001.$ First 15 rows of the table look as below, but should contain $\left\lceil{\log_{1.0001}(10)}\right\rceil  =23028$ rows in total.
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
n & 1.0001^n \\
\hline
0 & 1.0000000000 \\
1 & 1.0001000000 \\
2 & 1.0002000100 \\
3 & 1.0003000300 \\
4 & 1.0004000600 \\
5 & 1.0005001000 \\
6 & 1.0006001500 \\
7 & 1.0007002100 \\
8 & 1.0008002801 \\
9 & 1.0009003601 \\
10 & 1.0010004501 \\
11 & 1.0011005502 \\
12 & 1.0012006602 \\
13 & 1.0013007803 \\
14 & 1.0014009104 \\
15 & 1.0015010505 \\
\hline
\end{array}
But there should be a few more steps to complete his construction. Because this table (with 23028 entries) only allows us to multiply numbers as long as their product does not exceed 10, or the sum of corresponding logarithms does not exceed 23028. Can somebody, who has studied this, summarize to me how he overcame this challenge?

D. Roegel, "Bürgi’s Progress Tabulen (1620): logarithmic tables without logarithms." Res. Report Inria-00543936, 2010. J. Waldvogel, "Jost Bürgi and the discovery of the logarithms." Elem. Math. 69 (2014) 89-117 K.M. Clark & C. Montelle, "Priority, Parallel Discovery, and Pre-eminence Napier, Bürgi and the Early History of the Logarithm Relation." Revue d'histoire des mathématiques, Vol. 18 (2012), No. 2, pp. 223-270

Products larger than 10 can be handled by reducing the exponent of 1.0001 by multiples of $23027$, which removes factors of $10$ because $1.001^{23027}=9.99999780$ is extremely close to 10.
For example:
$3 \times6=1.0001^{10987} \times 1.0001^{17918}=1.0001^{28905}=1.0001^{23027} \times 1.0001^{5878}$.
$3 \times 6=1.0001^{23027} \times 1.0001^{5878}=10.00 \times 1.800=18$.
If you look at the original tables which are quite hard to read or the reproduction of the tables by Denis Roegel, you'll see that  Bürgi's tables have the "red numbers" (the logarithms) running from 0 to 230270 in steps of 10 and the "black numbers" running from 100000000 (100 million) to 999999780 (approximately one billion.) The red numbers are scaled by a factor of 10 while the black numbers are scaled by a factor of 100 million.
Repeating our calculation of $3 \times 6$ using Bürgi's table, we see that the red number corresponding to 300 million is 109870 and the red number corresponding to 600 million is 179180.  Adding these two red numbers gives a sum of 289050.  Reducing this sum by 230270 leaves 58780.  This red number of 58780 corresponds to the black number of 179997110, which is $1.8 \times 10^{8}$.

This is essentially the same thing that we do with logarithms to the base 10, except that in that case, we reduce the exponent of $10$ by integers.  e.g.  $3 \times 6=10^{0.47712} \times 10^{0.77815}=10^{1.2553}=10^{1}  \times 10^{0.2553}=10 \times 1.8=18.$

According to my calculations, it seems like $1.0001^{23027}$ is much closer to 10 compared to $1.0001^{23028}$. Do you know the actual number that Bürgi used?

I've updated the answer to correct the 23027 vs. 23028 error and to explain how the calculation is done with Burgi's original table.

Thank you for the detailed answer. I wish I could upvote again.
